# Rotational mechanics for ball

Tags: friction, rotational-kinematics

I got two questions

1)in pure rolling motion is angular acceleration and angular velocity same for a ball about its centre of mass and about its point of contact with ground?

2)if a ball is placed on an accelerating frame then at the point of contact with the frame how would the friction act?
Would it increase the linear acceleration or angular velocity (to achieve pure rolling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: taking the center of the ball as the center of the coordinate system, the angular acceleration $\alpha$ and angular velocity $\omega$ are the same as the angular acceleration $\alpha$ and angular velocity $\omega$ of the center of mass of the ball about the point at which the ball is rolling.

Friction always acts to oppose the current motion.  If the ball is not moving linearly nor rotating when it comes into contact with the accelerating surface, then friction will act to cause a torque to give an angular acceleration to the ball that will make the ball start rolling with the frame.  That same force of friction will also oppose the linear stasis of the ball, leading to a linear acceleration that will make the ball start moving in the same direction as the accelerating surface.

Edit per comment: If you draw a free body diagram, you'll see that friction will provide both the torque and force needed to angularly accelerate and linearly accelerate the ball in the correct directions at the same time.  For example, imagine the ball is originally stationary and is put into contact with a surface moving to the right.  Then the force of friction will also be to the right, and at the point of the contact of the ball with the surface.  Then the ball will start rotating counter-clockwise and will also begin moving linearly to the right.

Comment: But if friction acts in the direction of acceleration of frame,we would get linear accelerator but we can't get rolling in that case because torque will be backward on the ball

Comment: How to determine friction direction in such case

Comment: I got it but, finally.. When a body moves towards right and rotates counter clockwise can it be called pure rolling?

Comment: Pure rolling means there's a very specific relationship satisfied between the linear and rotational motion. When the ball first touches the moving surface, it will be moving, rotating, but also slipping. The ball will continue to slip until it comes to rest with respect to the moving surface, at which point it won't be rotating anymore, either.

Comment: What is the necessary condition for the ball to come to rest with respect to surface

Comment: v_ball = v_surface. The usual assumption for friction as $\mu N$ isn't quite right; what will happen is the ball will begin to decelerate as its velocity approaches that of the surface, and the ball will ultimately come to rest on the surface.